# how to calculate the distance between two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, distance, similarity

can you help me, I have 480(rows)*256(columns) which extracted by LBP operator.so i need to get the similarity matrices to apply the verification scenario.
 e.g vector one with itself will give zero and vector one with vector two will give score and so on 
why I am doing this, is because I need to calculate false accept rate and false reject rate
(FAR,FRR) by threshold.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) function. Note that it considers rows as instances (so you might want to transpose the matrix if you want to apply it to column vectors).

Comment: if i have this matrices [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] .
how I can use this function
thank u

Comment: @user3777182: and what do you consider as your vectors? Is it along the columns (`[1;4;7], [2;5;8], [3;6;9]`) or is it along the rows (`[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]`)? The code would be either `squareform(pdist(M))` or `squareform(pdist(M'))` depending on that..